# Removing 'mask' over Salesforce1 Mobile Cards

Tags: salesforce1-app

I was wondering if there was any way to remove the 'mask' over the Mobile Cards on an object's record details page that prevents them from being interactive until the user navigates into it.

The idea is to use the Mobile Card as a launchpad containing a link that navigates to another Visualforce page when the user taps on it. As it stands, the user would have to drill into the Mobile Card and then drill again to access the page in question.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry no. :(

The issue is in regards to scrolling, clicking on a mobile card would trap the scrolling actions and disrupt your ability to move around. As browsers mature I expect that the limitation will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much documentation on this - Salesforce overlays the iFrame that displays the Visualforce page in something like this:

```
<a class="mask" title="[your Visualforce page name]" href="javascript:void(0);" data-aura-rendered-by="64:325.a"><span class="assistiveText" data-aura-rendered-by="65:325.a">Expand</span></a>
```

This is outside of the iFrame, so you cannot modify it. In my case, I'm going to implement one action in a Visualforce page when tapped. When tapped on, the Visualforce page will load, detect that it's no longer inline, and then perform the action expected when it was tapped.

Unfortunately, it appears that all the URL parameters are the same - the Visualforce page doesn't know if it is inline or viewed after the mask was tapped. So what are we left with - checking window height?

Comment: Checking window height works as the VF inline will be shorter. Would be nice to get a url parameter added by SF to indicate inlineness...

Answer (score 0):

**Any embedded Visualforce pages in a standard layout will have to first be selected before they can be interacted with:**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221267&language=en_US&type=1